# use php to email information captured in contact form

Tags: php, forms, contacts

So I have a contact form and I want to send the captured information to an email. I think i am missing something with the structure of my code. really new to PHP. sorry if i sound dumb here.

Just updated the code below to reflect changes recommended in recent answers

```
    <form method="post" action="/home-value/">

<div class="hv-form">
<h4>Get Your Instant Home Value</h4>
<div class="street-row"><span class=""><input type="text" placeholder="Street" aria-invalid="false" class="" size="40" value="" name="Street"></span></div>

<div class="city-box"><span class=""><input type="text" placeholder="City" aria-invalid="false" class="" size="40" value="" name="City"></span></div>

<div class="state-box"><span><input type="text" placeholder="State" aria-invalid="false" size="40" value="" name="State"></span></div>

<div class="zip-box"><span ><input type="text" placeholder="Zip" aria-invalid="false"  size="40" value="" name="Zip"></span></div>
<div class="name-box"><span ><input type="text" placeholder="Name" aria-invalid="false"  size="40" value="" name="Name"></span></div>
<div class="phone-box"><span ><input type="tel" placeholder="Phone (Not Required)" aria-invalid="false"  size="40" value="" name="Phone"></span></div>
<div class="email-box"><span ><input type="email" placeholder="Email (Not Required)" aria-invalid="false"  size="40" value="" name="Email"></span></div>
<input type="hidden" name="form" id="form" value="form1" />
<div class="submit-box"><input type="submit" class="hv-submit" value="Get Home Value"></div>

</div>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['form']) && $_POST['form'] == 'form1')) {
$name=$_POST['Name'];
$name=$_POST['Name'];
$street=$_POST['Street'];
$email=$_POST['Email'];
$state=$_POST['State'];
$city=$_POST['City'];
$zip=$_POST['Zip'];
$phone=$_POST['Phone'];


// the message
$msg = "Street:".$street."\r\n" .
"City:".$city."\r\n" .
"State:".$state."\r\n" .
"Zip:".$zip."\r\n" .
"Name:".$name."\r\n" .
"Phone:".$phone."\r\n" .
"Email:".$email.;

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
$headers='From:Home Valuation Lead Form'."\n".'Reply-to:none';
$to ='briandresscc@gmail.com';
$subject='New Home Valuation Contact Form has been filled out on Angelandpatty.com';
// send email
mail($to,$subject,$msg, $headers);
}
?>


    <?PHP

}

?>
```

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Answer (score 0):

Your email is being sent before the form is processed, ergo your email is empty.

Try adding this line just before your submit button

```
<input type="hidden" name="form" id="form" value="form1" />
```

Then change this

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['Name'];
```

to this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['form']) && $_POST['form'] == 'form1') {
$name=$_POST['Name'];
```

and change this

```
mail($to,$subject,$msg, $headers);
?>
```

to this

```
mail($to,$subject,$msg, $headers);
}
?>
```

also, your message line should be coded as follows

```
$msg = "Street:".$street."\r\n" .
"City:".$city."\r\n" .
"State:".$state."\r\n" .
"Zip:".$zip."\r\n" .
"Name:".$name."\r\n" .
"Phone:".$phone."\r\n" .
"Email:".$email;
```

Then take your email code out of the form by moving your `</form>` tag above these lines

```
</div>
<?php
$name=$_POST['Name'];
```

All together it looks like this

```
<form method="post" action="/home-value/">
<div class="hv-form">
<h4>Get Your Instant Home Value</h4>
<div class="street-row"><span class=""><input type="text" placeholder="Street" aria-invalid="false" class="" size="40" value="" name="Street"></span></div>
<div class="city-box"><span class=""><input type="text" placeholder="City" aria-invalid="false" class="" size="40" value="" name="City"></span></div>
<div class="state-box"><span><input type="text" placeholder="State" aria-invalid="false" size="40" value="" name="State"></span></div>
<div class="zip-box"><span ><input type="text" placeholder="Zip" aria-invalid="false"  size="40" value="" name="Zip"></span></div>
<div class="name-box"><span ><input type="text" placeholder="Name" aria-invalid="false"  size="40" value="" name="Name"></span></div>
<div class="phone-box"><span ><input type="tel" placeholder="Phone (Not Required)" aria-invalid="false"  size="40" value="" name="Phone"></span></div>
<div class="email-box"><span ><input type="email" placeholder="Email (Not Required)" aria-invalid="false"  size="40" value="" name="Email"></span></div>
<input type="hidden" name="form" id="form" value="form1" />
<div class="submit-box"><input type="submit" class="hv-submit" value="Get Home Value"></div>

</div>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['form']) && $_POST['form'] == 'form1') {
$name=$_POST['Name'];
$street=$_POST['Street'];
$email=$_POST['Email'];
$state=$_POST['State'];
$city=$_POST['City'];
$zip=$_POST['Zip'];
$phone=$_POST['Phone'];

// the message
$msg = "Street:".$street."\r\n" .
"City:".$city."\r\n" .
"State:".$state."\r\n" .
"Zip:".$zip."\r\n" .
"Name:".$name."\r\n" .
"Phone:".$phone."\r\n" .
"Email:".$email;

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
$headers='From:Home Valuation Lead Form'."r\n".'Reply-to:none';
$to ='briandresscc@gmail.com';
$subject='New Home Valuation Contact Form has been filled out on Angelandpatty.com';
// send email
mail($to,$subject,$msg, $headers);
}
?>
```

Comment: i changed my msg to : 'street:'.$street.'\n';   and what is output is "Street:\n " in my email     It is not picking up ['Street'] from the form

Comment: i can send the email fine. It shows that it comes from Home Valuation Lead Formr  but it isnt picking up the information that is entered in the contact form

Comment: did i not do the $street=$_POST["Street"]  properly?

Comment: it is outputting\n in the email instead of making a line break as well

Comment: does the \r\n have to be in quotes?

Comment: so i put your lines in and now my page wont load at all so I am missing a comma or something

Comment: I looked at your updated answer and it looks right to me but I must be missing something because my entire site is just the white screen now

Comment: look at this line `if(isset($_POST['form']) && $_POST['form'] == 'form1') {` I removed a closing parenthesis... and this line... `"Email:".$email;`... I removed a period after `$email`

Comment: I made this change and now the email does not come through to my inbox

Comment: what is the page `/home-value/` ? Does it use any of the data submitted in the form?

Comment: so the data that is captured in this form is used to pull data from an api and display it on that page /home-value/

Comment: Okay... move your  entire email code from this page to the very top of the processing page... `/home-value/`  I mean at line 1 of the code, before `doctype`, `html` `head`

Comment: also, Why do you have an extra `<?php } ?>` tag in your code above?

Comment: OK I will try it. And can you please elaborate on the extra php tag

Comment: In your edited question above... at the very bottom, you have an extra `<?php } ?>`

Comment: it is a whole php file. im just trying to insert the mail form as an afterthought

Comment: But still, because your form action is taking the visitor from the form page to a processing page... if you want to process the email properly, it should be on the processing page as well.

Comment: @BrianDress - Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept that answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).
Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [Why is voting important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).